# Electron Preload - Context Bridge event to Quasar 2 Component

Tags: electron, vuejs3, knex.js, quasar-framework

When I want to send something to the main I call this from component `window.myAPI.addUser(formData)`

```js
     //electron.preload.js
     contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('myAPI',{
        addUser: (formData) => {
           ipcRenderer.invoke('add-user', formData)
        },
      })
```

And

```js
//electron-main.js
ipcMain.handle('myAPI:add-user', (formData) => {
    knex('users').insert(formData).then((result)=> {
       console.log(result)
    }).catch((err)=>{
        console.error(err);
    })
})
```

How can I listen any events from **ipcMain** inside my component?

I could not find any documentation about this in Quasar website

Answer (score 0):

this.$q.electron.ipcRenderer.invoke( 'blablabla' )

this.$q.electron.ipcMain.invoke( 'blablabla' )

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).